# Windows phone 8 app bing map coordinates shown with a pin. c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, pushpin

I have a problem finding a way to show the coordinates from a c# file as pins in bing maps.

I wrote this :

```
            var map = (FastFood.Grill)grill.SelectedItem;
            var map2 = (FastFood.Grill)grill.SelectedItem;
            BingMapsTask loc = new BingMapsTask();
            loc.Center = new GeoCoordinate(map.Map, map2.Map2);
            loc.Show();
```

Map is latitude and Map2 is longitude and I use the BingMapsTask and unite both of them on a single object, loc, and then I see the desired outcome/place on Bing Maps without making a new page with a map inside and writing more code. I want a way to make the shown location being shown with a pin.
Thanks!

Comment: Create a `PushPin` and set the `Location` property?

Comment: As far as I can see, [BingMapsTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.bingmapstask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class doesn't expose API that enable us to add Pin to it

Comment: @PeterRitchie unfortunately it doesn't let me do that.

Comment: @har07 So you mean I cant do anything to it ?

Comment: As I said, as far as I can see, yes can't do that with BingMapsTask. Seems that you have to built it "*manually*" using Map control.